# Why Play Framework handles my requests in sequence rather than asynchronously?

Tags: scala, playframework, netty, threadpool, future

I'm trying to understand how do asynchronous actions work in Play.
Documentation tell us that "Play handles every request in an asynchronous, non-blocking way". Suppose we have such example action in our Application controller:

```
def index = Action.async {
  Future {
    blocking{
      println("start at " + (new DateTime).toString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
      Thread.sleep(10000) // 10 seconds
      println("end at " + (new DateTime).toString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
      Ok("Done")
    }
  }
}
```

I make "activator run", then I open two tabs in my browser and make a request to this Action in each of them.
And in my console I see something like this:

```
start at 09-11-2015 18:33:34
end at 09-11-2015 18:33:44
start at 09-11-2015 18:33:44
end at 09-11-2015 18:33:54
```

So, the handling of my second request begins only after the first request handling ends.

I have tried to configure thread pool as described in [this article](https://violoncello2011.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/play-framework-thread-tuning/), but result has not changed.

Why Play handles my requests in sequence rather than in parallel?

Comment: See the second paragraph of the linked answer, specifically.

Comment: I have tried to run activator in production mode, but result does not change. What should I do to execute a blocking code in a different thread?

Comment: You are using `activator start` ? What execution context are you importing? Thread pool config?

Comment: No "activator start" is deprecated in Play 2.4. I run "activator stage" and then execute generated script from target/universal/stage/bin. I'm using standard play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext and default config.

Comment: I did a lot of experiments and found one thing. Maybe it sounds crazy, but Play handles simultaneous requests sequentially only if they are made from the same browser to the same route. If I make requests via curl or from different browsers or even from one browser but to different routes, then they are handled asynchronously. Not sure what kind of protection Play does in such a way, but this protection exists and it's a fact.